# How to create grade system in prolog

Tags: prolog

Menu Score Kelulusan

- Score get from UTS = 70% and UAS = 30%
- if score >=90  Lulus dengan Grade A
- if score >=80  Lulus dengan Grade B
- if score >=70  Lulus dengan Grade C
- if score >=60  Tidak Lulus dengan Grade D
- if score <=59  Tidak Lulus dengan Grade E

Note: i had seen someone making similiar prolog grading system, but i have more Grade category than the guy who answer the question. i got an error when try adding more grade category using their code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using strict ordering:

```
score_grade(90, 'A').
score_grade(80, 'B').
score_grade(70, 'C').
score_grade(60, 'D').
score_grade(0,  'E').

calc_score_grade(Score, Grade) :-
    score_grade(ScoreMin, Grade),
    Score >= ScoreMin,
    % Don't backtrack after finding first
    !.
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- calc_score_grade(75, G).
G = 'C'.
```